# Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for ActivityDeparturesBinding not found

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, dagger-2, android-databinding

I have a separate Android library in a separate project for an Android app. However I link the library directly (referencing the library module directly by path or the generated AAR) I get the following error:

```
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':app:kaptDevelopDebugKotlin'.
> Cannot write to file '/home/m0skit0/Repos/repo/app-android/app/build/intermediates/data-binding/develop/debug/bundle-bin' specified for property 'dataBindingArtifactOutputDir' as it is a directory.

e: error: cannot access ActivityDeparturesBinding
  class file for com.blablabla.databinding.ActivityDeparturesBinding not found
  Consult the following stack trace for details.
  com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for com.blablabla.databinding.ActivityDeparturesBinding not found

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDevelopDebugKotlin'.
```

This shows just after the task `:app:transformDataBindingWithDataBindingMergeArtifactsForDevelopDebug`

However the class does exist, with full canonical name. It belongs to the the library and it is correctly auto generated (without any errors) by Android's Data Binding processor on both projects. The library compiles correctly on its own. There's no further stacktrace even if the compilation is run with `--stacktrace`.

I have tried linking the library with compile, implementation and api, all with the same result.

Gradle version is 4.4.

---

UPDATE:

Updating to Gradle 5 did not solve the problem. Renaming the XML did not solve the problem.

I've also found that the error happens only when I reference the `ActivityDeparturesBinding` class in my code, even if the part where it is referenced is never actually called. Only importing it without referencing it does not cause the error.

---

UPDATE2:

This is the activity that uses the layout:

```
class DeparturesActivity : BaseVinPlateActivity<DeparturesViewModel, ActivityDeparturesBinding>() {

    companion object {
        fun getStartIntent(context: Context) = Intent(context, DeparturesActivity::class.java)
    }

    @Inject
    override lateinit var viewModel: DeparturesViewModel

    override val layout: Int = R.layout.activity_departures

    override fun injectThis(component: ActivityComponent) {
        component.inject(this)
    }

    override fun getToolbarTitleId(): Int = R.string.departures_title

    override fun initializeDataBindings(dataBinding: ActivityDeparturesBinding) {
        dataBinding.viewmodel = viewModel
    }
}

abstract class BaseVinPlateActivity<T: BaseVinPlateViewModel, U: ViewDataBinding> : CompoundsBaseActivity()  {

    protected abstract var viewModel: T
    protected abstract val layout: Int

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == BARCODE_RESULT_CODE_ACTIVITY && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            val barcodeResult = data?.getStringExtra(BARCODE_RESULT_ACTIVITY)
            viewModel.setBarcodeResult(barcodeResult)
        }
    }

    override fun initializeView() {
        super.initializeView()
        val dataBinding = inflateDataBinding<U>(layout)
        initializeDataBindings(dataBinding)
        with (viewModel) {
            setBindValidator(Validator(dataBinding))
            loadData()
        }
    }

    protected abstract fun initializeDataBindings(dataBinding: U)
}
```

If I remove the `initializeDataBindings()` function, the error is gone. Note that commenting only the body of the function is not enough, I had to remove the whole function.

This smells like a compiler/tools bug.

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/solved-gradle-5-3-error-android-task-kaptbetadebugkotlin-failed/31130 mentions the exact same problem, suggesting to update the gradle android plugin version

Comment: @Zbynek I don't think that error is related. When the compilation is successful that error is also shown a couple of times.

Comment: anyway, what version of Android gradle plugin are you using? Did you try updating to 3.3.2+?

Comment: @Zbynek It is an old project, it is using Gradle 4.4, I don't remember the Android gradle plugin version. I will try your suggestion, however we fixed the problem, I will post an answer soon. Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could bypass the compilation error in a couple of ways (there are probably more ways). The best way we came up with is converting the abstract function into an abstract lambda property.

Parent class:

```
abstract class BaseVinPlateActivity<T: BaseVinPlateViewModel, U: ViewDataBinding> : CompoundsBaseActivity()  {

    protected abstract val initializeDataBinding: U.() -> Unit

    // Rest of code
}
```

Child class:

```
class DeparturesActivity : BaseVinPlateActivity<DeparturesViewModel, ActivityDeparturesBinding>() {

    override val initializeDataBinding: ActivityDeparturesBinding.() -> Unit = { viewmodel = this@DeparturesActivity.viewModel }

    // Rest of code    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know it's late but I'd like to say that something similar happened to me, in my case I have a library module which was using a third party library, and then in my app module I'm using dagger for injecting dependencies, and I was getting this issue because, I believe dagger couldn't find this thrid party library's class because it wasn't directly implemented in the app's dependencies. So in my case what got it sorted was to change the way I was adding the third party library into my local library module in order to use `api` instead of `implementation`.